# Sitecore: general link with search

Tags: search, hyperlink, sitecore

I have created "general link with search" field type in Sitecore content editor. I would like to be able to search custom items by name/id. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your general link with search field should have a "Search for a link" button/link on top of it (first one, just before "Insert link"). Clicking that opens a search window where you can use the search functionalities of Sitecore to select an item to link to. This includes searching on name or id.

To search on a name, just type the name you want in the search field. To search on id, first type "id:" and enter the id in the provided id box.

Comment: it seems that it searches English version of items. How can I search by all/specific language?

Comment: To search in a specific language, start typing "lang.." and you will get the language search box - note that you can select the languages in the box, which is easier as it needs the name and not the code (e.g. Russian, not ru)

Comment: there is "0 results" for any language except English. But I am sure I have items in other language. Do you know what can be the reason of this issue?

Comment: Could be that your indexes are not up-to-date. If not, I would contact Sitecore Support to figure it out.

Comment: I have rebuild indexes and tried to find an item by ID again withour success. Could you have a look on the query from log, please? It looks like "en" value is set up somewhere in config files:8128 13:01:30 INFO  Serialized Query - ?q=(((_content:(2718510) OR _name:(2718510) OR _displayname:(2718510) OR parsedlanguage_s:(swedish_sweden)) AND (_path:(11111111111111111111111111111111) AND _latestversion:(1))) AND _datasource:(sitecore))&start=0&rows=20&fl=*,score&fq=_indexname:(sitecore_master_index)&fq=_language:(en*)

Comment: This is what I get when searching for anything in "dutch": (sitecore_master_index): +_datasource:sitecore +(+(+_path:11111111111111111111111111111111 +_latestversion:1) +(parsedlanguage:dutch (_content:* _name:* _displayname:*))) - Filter :  and this for an ID search: (sitecore_master_index): +_datasource:sitecore +(+(+_path:11111111111111111111111111111111 +_latestversion:1) +(+_path:154d56cc0de243c7bbc0a25bd7ffd901 +(+_path:154d56cc0de243c7bbc0a25bd7ffd901 +(-_group:154d56cc0de243c7bbc0a25bd7ffd901 +*:*)))) - Filter :

Comment: I would contact Sitecore Support if the field is not working ootb.. (as it should)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I think I have to figure out how to remove "&fq=_languag‌​e:(en*)" part from the query to get items in other languages.